# Possible bug in python re

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code:

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'[*-/]')
print r.match('.') is not None
```

It prints `True`, signifying that `'.'` matches the given regular expression, which it doesn't. Am I missing something obvious in the regex?

I'm using cpython `2.7.3` on osx `10.8.2`

If any of the three characters inside the `[]` set are removed, it works.

Comment: special characters lose their meaning inside sets: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you write the following,

```
r = re.compile(r'[*-/]')
```

The use of `-` really means match any character between `*` and `/`. If you look at the ascii table,

```
*      42
+      43
,      44
-      45
.      46
/      47
```

And that is why it matches the `.` character. Your current regex also will match,

```
>>> print r.match('+')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x100483370>
>>> print r.match(',')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x100483370>
```

To correct the regex so that it only matches `*` or `-` or `/`, you can escape the `-` like this,

```
r = re.compile(r'[*\-/]')
```

Then you don't get a match for `.`

```
>>> print r.match('.') is not None
False
```

Comment: You can also put the `-` last: `r'[*/-]'`.

Comment: one of those things where it's obvious once it's pointed out. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Compile it using `re.DEBUG`

```
In [3]: r = re.compile(r'[*-/]', re.DEBUG)
in
  range (42, 47)
```

which gives the definition of the range. `man ascii` gives

```
42        *
43        +
44        ,
45        -
46        .
47        /
```

which includes a `.` hence perfectly legal.